# Interpretation of piecewise mixed effects output

Tags: r, effects, mixed, piecewise

I am trying to understand the summary output from a piecewise mixed effects model and could use some insight. Specifically, I want to know how I get the regression intercepts and slopes for the line left and right of the breakpoint. From what I understand, the intercept given in the output below is for the regression line left of the breakpoint and the value given for I(Days * (Days < 6.07)) is the slope of that line. However, I don't think I(Days * (Days >= 6.07)) is the slope for the line right of the breakpoint, nor is it the difference in the two slopes.

```
library(lme4)
sleepstudy<-as.data.frame(sleepstudy)
```

I pulled the break point from a previous thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/estimating-the-break-point-in-a-broken-stick-piecewise-linear-model-with-rando

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ I(Days * (Days < 6.07)) + I(Days * (Days >= 6.07)) +      (1 | Subject) 
   Data: sleepstudy 

REML criterion at convergence: 1784.369 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 1377.6   37.12   
 Residual              965.7   31.08   
Number of obs: 180, groups: Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)              252.2663    10.0545  25.090
I(Days * (Days < 6.07))   10.0754     1.3774   7.315
I(Days * (Days >= 6.07))  10.4513     0.8077  12.940

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) I(*(<6
I(D*(D<6.07 -0.409       
I(D*(D>=6.0 -0.374  0.630
```

I tried to simplify by removing the random effect:
When I() is included in the lm model, the slope/intercepts are very similar to the mixed model above and I am still confused.

> mod_lm<-lm(Reaction ~ I(Days*(Days < 6.07)) + I(Days*(Days>= 6.07)), data = sleepstudy)
>   summary(mod_lm)

```
Call:
lm(formula = Reaction ~ I(Days * (Days < 6.07)) + I(Days * (Days >= 
    6.07)), data = sleepstudy)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-111.581  -27.632    1.614   26.994  141.443 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               252.266      7.629  33.066  < 2e-16 ***
I(Days * (Days < 6.07))    10.075      2.121   4.751 4.17e-06 ***
I(Days * (Days >= 6.07))   10.451      1.243   8.405 1.37e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 47.84 on 177 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2867,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2786 
F-statistic: 35.57 on 2 and 177 DF,  p-value: 1.037e-13
```

When the I() is removed from the lm formula, however, I understand the output, and the results make sense.

> mod_lm<-lm(Reaction ~ Days*(Days < 6.07) + Days*(Days>= 6.07), data = sleepstudy)
>   summary(mod_lm)

```
Call:
lm(formula = Reaction ~ Days * (Days < 6.07) + Days * (Days >= 
    6.07), data = sleepstudy)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-114.214  -27.833    0.603   27.254  141.693 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)            207.008     64.211   3.224  0.00151 **
Days                    16.050      7.985   2.010  0.04595 * 
Days < 6.07TRUE         45.908     64.671   0.710  0.47872   
Days >= 6.07TRUE            NA         NA      NA       NA   
Days:Days < 6.07TRUE    -6.125      8.265  -0.741  0.45965   
Days:Days >= 6.07TRUE       NA         NA      NA       NA   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 47.91 on 176 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2887,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2766 
F-statistic: 23.81 on 3 and 176 DF,  p-value: 5.526e-13
```

When the I() terms are removed from the lmer formula, however the lmer won't run.

```
mod1<-lmer(Reaction ~ Days*(Days < 6.07) + Days*(Days>= 6.07) + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
Error in lme4::lFormula(formula = Reaction ~ Days * (Days < 6.07) + Days *  : 
  rank of X = 4 < ncol(X) = 6
```

Could someone either tell me how to interpret the lmer() output when I() is used on the model predictors, or tell me how to run the lmer() model without the I() on the model predictors?

I appreciate any guidance available as I have not been able to find anything on R help pages for this one!

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why the `lmer` results with `I()` don't make sense to you.  Plotting the data, the slope is indeed pretty consistently +10 seconds per day; 10.08 seconds/day before day 6 and 10.45 seconds/day after day 6 makes sense to me.  In contrast, your `lm()` fit (besides being overparameterized) suggests that the slope is 10 when `Days<6.07` and jumps up to 16 for the last 3 days -- this *might* make sense given (1) we ignore random effects and (2) we allow both slope and intercept to vary by period (the first models here assume the intercept is the same for both periods).

Answer (score 5):

I think you can get what you want as follows:

```
library(lme4)
sleepstudy <- transform(sleepstudy,period=(Days<6.5))
(m0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days+ (1 | Subject), sleepstudy))
(m2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days*period+ (1 | Subject), sleepstudy))
## 
## Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
## Formula: Reaction ~ Days * period + (1 | Subject) 
##    Data: sleepstudy 
## REML criterion at convergence: 1773.86 
## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
##  Subject  (Intercept) 37.12   
##  Residual             31.06   
## Number of obs: 180, groups: Subject, 18
## Fixed Effects:
##     (Intercept)             Days       periodTRUE  Days:periodTRUE  
##         207.008           16.050           45.908           -6.125
```

Your results with `I()` are constructing numeric variables rather than categorical variables (which are converted into dummy variables).  Perhaps the main reason for your confusion is that your first set of models doesn't allow for separate intercepts by period, only separate slopes ...

The reason that `lmer` didn't work for your second set of models is that `lmer` is not as tolerant of overparameterization (multicollinear predictors) as `lm` is, although the development version (available on Github, and soon to be released) is: if you run your `mod1` it will fit the model and print a message "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients" (unlike `lm`, it doesn't retain the dropped columns with `NA` coefficients, just drops them entirely).

**Update**:

```
sleepstudy <- transform(sleepstudy,cDays=Days-6.5)
m3 <- lmer(Reaction ~ cDays:period+ (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())    
library(reshape2)
g0 <- ggplot(sleepstudy,aes(Days,Reaction,group=Subject))+geom_line()
pframe <- data.frame(Days=seq(0,8,length=101))
pframe <- transform(pframe,cDays=Days-6.5,period=Days>6.5)
## next line assumes latest version of lme4 -- you may need REform instead
pframe$Reaction <- predict(m3,newdata=pframe,re.form=NA)
pframe$Reaction2 <- predict(m0,newdata=pframe,re.form=NA)
```

It's a bit hard to see the difference in slopes -- pretty subtle.

```
g0 + geom_line(data=pframe,colour=2,aes(group=NA))+
     geom_line(data=pframe,colour=2,lty=2,
         aes(y=Reaction2,group=NA))+
     geom_vline(xintercept=6.5,lty=2)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. I am posting a question/comment in the answer box to follow up.

Comment: This is super interesting, is it possible to do a piecewise lmer when you have a treatment categorical variable that has c(Control, DrugA,DrugB) and that from time (0,20) you stop treatment, and then from that last time point 20 you stop the treatment and the you wait another 20 days to see what happen (20,40). In this case you would know that your knot or break is at 20. Can I still apply what you specified in your answer ?

Comment: Also, in your update mode m3 you pit the interaction cDays:period. but here with this sleepstudy <- transform(sleepstudy,cDays=Days-6.5) data. You don't have that variable so it would be just cDays ?